# Swift: JSONDecoder + Codable

Tags: json, swift

I have three classes whom I want to parse from json which I receive from a server. the json structure is currenct.

those classes are:

```
public class HmoModel: Codable {
    private var Id: Int
    private var Name: String
}

public class SplashModel: Codable {
    public var Hmos: [HmoModel]!
}

public class PatientSplashModel: SplashModel {
    public var StressorsAnswers: [StressorsAnswerModel]!
}
```

I'm trying to parse a json this way:

```
do {
    let patientSplash = try self.decoder.decode(PatientSplashModel.self, from: response.data)
} catch {
    listener.onException(error)
}
```

but in patientSplash everything is nil.

I'm receiving the json using SwiftHTTP like this

```
HTTP.GET(ServerPatientApi.SPLASH, parameters: nil) { response in
            if let error = response.error {
                listener.onException(error)
                return;
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: {
                do {
                    listener.onSplashLoaded(try self.decoder.decode(PatientSplashModel.self, from: response.data))
                } catch {
                    listener.onException(error)
                }
            })
        }
```

How to fix it? Hot to make a decoder parse json?

Thanks!

Comment: And is there an error thrown? What you JSON looks like? Because the code seems valid, but we can't guess what went wrong. Also, name your var starting with a lowercase (in your Model).

Comment: There isn't an error

Comment: There isn't any exceptions too

Comment: post the json ....

Comment: I'm using the same API within android which working perfectly so I guess there is no need to print huge string of the json but I did added the way I'm receiving that json. may there is an error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

please add **Codingkeys enum** to your codable classes so codable could get objects by key for example

```
public class HmoModel: Codable {
    private var Id: Int
    private var Name: String
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case Id="id"
       case Name="name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Here a part of the JSON response for HmoModel:

Comment: "Hmos":[{"Id":1,"Name":"None"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Clalit"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Meuhedet"},{"Id":4,"Name":"Maccabi"}]

Comment: I have added the enum but they are still nil(((

Comment: 1 commandlineflags.cc:1503] Ignoring RegisterValidateFunction() for flag pointer 0x10d8f8980: no flag found at that address

Comment: @AndreySerdyuk i don't think this error is relative to codable thing at all. 
and please remember when you are using codable with classes and inheritance you should add required init function to child classes too. also every codable class should have their CodingKeys enum you can read more about this at https://medium.com/tsengineering/swift-4-0-codable-decoding-subclasses-inherited-classes-heterogeneous-arrays-ee3e180eb556